# Kotlin and swift full map navigation speed

Tags: swift, dictionary, kotlin, iteration, mutablemap

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to navigate maps in kotlin (and swift), when you need to navigate the whole map.
Both languages offer a .values method that make the navigation simpler, but with a C++ background I thought it could not perform in a decent way since it should create a vector of values with an additional navigation of the map (and a relevant memory allocation).

Basically my question is about this code:

```
val map: MutableMap<Int, String> = mutableMapOf()

for (i in 1.. 1000000) {
    map[i] = "Value of this element is $i"
}

for (v in map.values)
    if (v[0] != 'V')
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR!")

for ((_, v) in map) // it should be faster!
    if (v[0] != 'V')
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR!")
```

... I've done a few benchmark of this code, timing the results with System.currentTimeMillis() and using one or two different maps, to avoid cache effects...

But I cannot get meaningful results... here is a complete program in kotlin native, that shows (differently from kotlin on JVM) a behaviour that is the contrary of the one I expected, I used two different maps and two tests per algorithm to exclude cache advantages.

```
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() {
    val m1 : MutableMap<Int, String> = mutableMapOf()
    val m2 : MutableMap<Int, String> = mutableMapOf()

    println("Creating map...")
    var st = getTimeMillis()
    for (i in 1..2000000) {
        m1[i] = "Test $i"
        m2[i] = "Test $i"
    }

    var end = getTimeMillis()
    println("Took: ${end - st} msecs, map size: ${m1.size},${m2.size} elements")

    st = getTimeMillis()
    for ((_, v) in m1)
        if (v[0] != 'T')
            println("ERROR!");
    end = getTimeMillis()
    println("Algorithm 1 (k,v): ${end - st} msecs")

    st = getTimeMillis()
    for (v in m2.values)
        if (v[0] != 'T')
            println("ERROR!");
    end = getTimeMillis()
    println("Algorithm 2 (values): ${end - st} msecs")

    st = getTimeMillis()
    for ((_, v) in m2)
        if (v[0] != 'T')
            println("ERROR!");
    end = getTimeMillis()
    println("Algorithm 1bis (k,v): ${end - st} msecs")

    st = getTimeMillis()
    for (v in m1.values)
        if (v[0] != 'T')
            println("ERROR!");
    end = getTimeMillis()
    println("Algorithm 2bis (values): ${end - st} msecs")
}
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that it should be faster?

Comment: You haven't asked a clear question but I assume it is how to perform micro bench marking?

Comment: Added an example program for clarity, I want to understand if and why iterate on map.values may be faster than on the map itself.